# Alternative to blocktrans tag with long `with` clause

Tags: django, django-templates, internationalization, readability, django-context

## Context

I'm trying to use the django template engine to render translatable part of a page using variable from the context. Specifically, this is my use case

```
{% blocktrans trimmed with type=training.type title=training.title city=training.city %}
Training {{ type }} "{{ title }}" at {{ city }}
{% endblocktrans %}
```

This works fine, however, my issue with it that the `blocktrans` length grows very quicky above the acceptable (at least, for me).

As an alternative, I could do

```
    {% with training.title as title %}
    {% with training.type as type %}
    {% with training.city as city %}
    {% blocktrans trimmed %}
    Training {{ type }} "{{ title }}" at {{ city }}
    {% endblocktrans %}
    {% endwith %}
    {% endwith %}
    {% endwith %}
```

Or using one separate with clause.

But that does not really ease the readability of that code, especially if there is more variables to expose to the translation string.

## Solution I thought of

My initial idea was to extends the blocktrans tag onto several lines :

```
{% blocktrans trimmed with 
    type=training.type
    title=training.title
    city=training.city %}
Training {{ type }} "{{ title }}" at {{ city }}
{% endblocktrans %}
```

Unfortunately for me, django does not support multilline tags in templates.

(see the rather lengthy dicussion on django [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-developers/wRKgnMIhl6g/A7MdArOlufwJ) for the why).

## Question

Since I did not find in the above mentioned discussion a solution, I'm searching for a way to obtain the same result as in my first code, without hampering my templates readability with overly long lines/big blocks of `with` tags.

I thought about putting that code elsewhere, like a `@property` methods in the model `training` is based on. But it seems to me that the that logic belongs to the template, (it's very unlikely it will be used anywhere else).

Is there a alternative, idiomatic way to achieve this in django ?

Comment: Maybe this is the solution ? I am not sure it's working ...

    `{% blocktrans trimmed with t=training %}
    Training {{ t.type }} "{{ t.title }}" at {{ t.city }}
    {% endblocktrans %}`

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work^.

Answer (score 0):

One way to to do this is to create a custom template tag for setting the variables inside the template

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def setvar(val):
    return val
```

and in template

```
{% load setvar %}
{% setvar training.title as title %}
{% setvar training.type as type %}
{% setvar training.city as city %}
{% blocktrans trimmed %}
    Training {{ type }} "{{ title }}" at {{ city }}
{% endblocktrans %}
```

This also supports filters, for example

```
{% setvar training.title|title as title %}
```